# given a sorted array arr, find three i < k < n such that arr[i] + arr[k] + arr[n] = t

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to solve this problem of given a sorted array `arr`, find three indices `i`, `k`, `n`, and `i < k < n` such that `arr[i] + arr[k] + arr[n] = t`. The array is guaranteed to have at least one solution.

When I follow my algorithm I arrive at the result, however, I have a an empty list as a result, what is the problem?

This is my attempt:

```
def threeSumSort(lst, t):
  res = []
  i, n = 0, len(lst)-1
  k = (n // 2)
  while (i < k < n):
    pt = lst[i] + lst[k] + lst[n]
    if pt == t:
      res.append([i+1, k+1,n+1])
      return res
    elif (pt > t):
      if (pt - lst[k] - lst[n-1]) + lst[k-1] + lst[n-1] > t:
        n -= 1
        k -= 1
      elif (pt - lst[k]) + lst[k-1] > t:
        k -= 1
      elif (pt - lst[n]) + lst[n-1] > t:
        n -= 1
    else:
      if (pt - lst[k] - lst[i+1]) + lst[k+1] + lst[i+1] < t:
        i += 1
        k += 1
      elif (pt - lst[k]) + lst[k+1] < t:
        k += 1
      elif (pt - lst[i]) + lst[i+1] < t:
        i += 1
  return res

lst = [0,2,3,5,10,13]
print(threeSumSort(lst, 8))
```

I am using three pointers, but the cases are infinite, what would be the best time complexity algorithm?

Comment: Didn't you ask about the same code earlier?

Comment: Can you add a link to the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: This would be a great time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: The problem is that the algorithm is wrong. People are usually using an O(n^2) algo for such contests. Faster algorithms exist but they are research level stuff. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM

Comment: Can all three values be a) > t/3 b) < t/3?

Comment: @greybeard  t values are random

Answer (score 0):

This can be done more simply. Just iterate `i` and `n` so that they're always apart by at least 2 (so there's room for `k` between them). Then check if the difference between `t` and `lst[i] + lst[n]` is between them, and get its index into `k`.

```
def threeSumSort(lst, t):
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        first = lst[i]
        if first > t:
            break

        for n in range(i+2, len(lst)):
            last = lst[n]
            middle = t - first - last
            if middle < lst[0]:
                break

            try:
                k = lst.index(middle, i+1, n)
                return i, k, n
            except ValueError:
                pass

lst = [0,2,3,5,10,13]
print(threeSumSort(lst, 8)) # (0, 2, 3)
```

Comment: @greybeard (1) The OP asked two questions. This doesn't answer either of them. (2) Cubic complexity for a problem usually solved in quadratic time. (3) Fails input `[1,1,1], 3`. (4) First two lines are pointless, those `i` and `n` get overwritten. (5) Ends with a crash, due to using `//` instead of `#`.

Comment: @KellyBundy (1) I can't understand the OP's code, it's too confusing, so I can't tell why it doesn't work. (3) I assumed the list was monotonically increasing, need to change `<=` to `<` to handle duplicates. (4) I forgot to remove those lines when I copied OP's code. (5) Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you're getting a blank list is because of the logic in the `elif` and `else` conditions. Based on one variable, you are unit incrementing or decrementing the other two variables, whereas, for the logic that you're trying to implement, the gap can be more than one.

You can solve the problem in the following manner:

here, `t` is your final result, so if you're traversing through the list, for any value `x` in the list, the other two variables' sum should be `t-x`, and similarly for the remaining two variables, you can easily calculate with `t-x` as the result.

```
def two_sum(arr, result):
    values = {}
    
    for x in range(len(arr)):
        if result-arr[x] in values:
            return (values[result-arr[x]], x)
        
        else:
            values[arr[x]] = x


def three_sum(arr, result):
    for x in range(len(arr)-2):
        other_two = two_sum(arr[x+1:], result-arr[x])
        if other_two:
            return [x, other_two[0]+x+1, other_two[0]+x+1] # as the arr passed to two_sum was relative, getting absolute indices of those values
        

arr = [0,2,3,5,10,13]
print(three_sum(arr, 8))
```

This is the simplified solution to your problem, having `O(n^2)` time complexity.

The output of this code is as follows and was correct:

```
[0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the gap can be more than one" and how is that an issue?

Comment: @KellyBundy, for the given example, the indices are `[0, 2, 3]` which is there is a difference of two between `i` and `k`, in the logic, OP is checking at the interval of `1` and incrementing/decrementing by `1` only.

Comment: @KellyBundy, if you add a print statement in OP's code, you'll realize, the output is `0 2 5` then `0 1 4` because `k` and `n` were both decremented simulatenously.

Comment: Yes, they start with `0 2 5`, so they *could* reach `0 2 3` by doing `n -= 1` three times. And they do have a code path that does only `n -= 1`. They just don't do that. Maybe a more "meaningful" explanation just doesn't exist. I can tell that their `- lst[n-1]` should be `- lst[n]` (and likewise for the other case), but beyond that, I can't do much better than "Your algorithm is just wrong, there's no reason it should work". Anyway... you could improve your algorithm, taking advantage of the sortedness you can do this in O(n^2) time and O(1) space.

Comment: @KellyBundy, the issue is that it isn't going for only the `n-=1` path, it is going on the first path where both `k` and `n` are decremented twice, and comes to `0 1 4` and then goes to only `k -= 1` path which goes to `i = k` as they are both `0`, canceling the while loop

Comment: Yes, I understand you now, it just doesn't feel like a very "meaningful" explanation. What if they remove the paths that increase/decrease two variables together? Would it work then?

Comment: @KellyBundy, it wouldn't work by removing it as even the OP's current logic itself is incomplete for now. Not seeing any sure-shot way to implement this algorithm in linear time, which OP is trying.

Comment: It's an open research problem whether it can be done in even just O(n^(2-epsilon)), so yeah, we're extremely unlikely to find a linear time solution :-)

Comment: @Zero Yes, but I am trying to solve it using pointers not with hashing

Comment: @Kim, not using hashing will make it all the more complicated, and can't be achieved in O(n) with any present data structures or algorithms so far.

Comment: Yes, but with pointers it is also possible to do `O(n^2)`: https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/solutions/7392/python-easy-to-understand-solution-o-n-n-time/

Comment: I agree, it is possible in O(n^2), but your code's complexity is O(n), as there's only one loop therefore it isn't suitable for this problem.

Comment: @Zero Theirs is **not** O(n), it can even run **endlessly**.

Comment: Yeah @KellyBundy, not going with the logic but with asymptotic notation.

Comment: Also, "only one loop" in general doesn't automatically mean O(n). Depends on the loop.

Comment: *"not going with the logic but with asymptotic notation"* - That also doesn't make sense. You can't do the asymptotic notation without looking at the logic.

Comment: @KellyBundy what do you mean endlessly, you mean if there is no such three numbers? But the problem assumes that at least there is one solution.

Comment: @Zero `return [x, other_two[0]+x+1, other_two[0]+x+1] ` why did you repeat the same `other_two[0]+x+1` ? Did you mean `other_two[1]+x+1`

Comment: Yes, I meant the latter one, my bad there.

Comment: @Kim For example `threeSumSort([0,4,5,9,10], 14)`

Comment: Sorry @KellyBundy, it seems I might be confusing, you're correct.